# Making Form at Wordpress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm a self learner so I didnt had anyone to get a clue, I wan't to make a form with POST method and I take w3 tutorial to make one.

[PHP Form Validation Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete)

I successfully make it, and I want to make it included at wordpress theme, so I put those codes at page templates, just like this

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Urut Embed
*/
 get_header();
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $videocodeErr =  $embedurlErr = "";
$name = $videocode = $embed = $embedurl = $embedurut[] = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["embedurl"])) {
        $embedurl = "";
    } else {
        $embedurl = test_input($_POST["embedurl"]);
        // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular     expression also allows dashes in the URL)
        if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$embedurl)) {
            $embedurlErr = "Invalid URL"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["videocode"])) {
        $videocode = "";
    } else {
        $videocode = test_input($_POST["videocode"]);
        // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
        if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$videocode)) {
            $videocodeErr = "Invalid URL"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["embed"])) {
        $embed = "";
    } else {
        $embed = test_input($_POST["embed"]);
        if($videocode == "sf"){
            $embedurut = str_replace("http://www.savefile.co/","sf;", $embed);
            $embedurut = str_replace(" savefile.co.",".", $embed);
        } else if($videocode == "mp4"){
            $embedurut = str_replace("https://www.mp4upload.com/"," mp4;", $embed);
        } else if($videocode == "yu"){
            $embedurut = str_replace("https://www.yourupload.com/embed/","yu;", $embed);
        } else if($videocode == "gk"){
            $embedurut = str_replace("|"," - gk;", $embed);
        } else {
            $embedurut = $embed;
        }
        $embedurut = str_replace($name,"", $embedurut);
        $embedurut = explode(PHP_EOL, $embedurut);
        sort($embedurut);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Urut Embed Videocode</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Remove Strings</span>
            <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan bagian videocode yang ingin dihilangkan" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
            Check sesuai dengan embed video untuk mengubah link menjadi videocode, none jika tidak ingin mengubah.
        </div>

        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="videocode" <?php if (isset($videocode) && $videocode=="none"){ echo "checked"; } else if ($videocode==""){ echo "checked"; } ?> value="none">None</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="videocode" <?php if (isset($videocode) && $videocode=="sf") echo "checked";?> value="sf">SaveFile</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="videocode" <?php if (isset($videocode) && $videocode=="mp4") echo "checked";?> value="mp4">MP4Upload</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="videocode" <?php if (isset($videocode) && $videocode=="yu") echo "checked";?> value="yu">YourUpload</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="videocode" <?php if (isset($videocode) && $videocode=="gk") echo "checked";?> value="gk">gk</label>
        <br><br>

        <span class="label label-primary">
            Embeds
        </span>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="embed" rows="5" cols="150"><?php echo $embed;?></textarea>
        <br>

        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>
    <br>

    <span class="label label-primary">
        Embed Terurut
    </span>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="embed" rows="12" cols="150"><?php
    $alength = count($embedurut);
    for($x = 0; $x < $alength; $x++) {
    echo $embedurut[$x];
    }
    ?></textarea>
</div>
```

But when I ran it, it comes back with 404 page, but with the page url, not 404 url. I dont have any clue at all how to make it work.
Can you guys help me? Sorry for bad English.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make page from wordpress admin dashboard and call this template and then run the page.

Comment: Sorry for late reply

I mean, I already run that, but when I click the submit button, its redirecting to itself page and showing 404.

Comment: I never touch the .htaccess file, what I need to change there?

Comment: You will get the updated **.htaccess** file in wordpress admin dashboard under **settings** > **permalinks** just copy and paste code inside your folder

Answer (score 0):

- Go to wordpress add new page.
- Give the page a title.
- And select "Urut Embed" as template to this page
- Save and view the page.

Comment: Sorry for late reply

I mean, I already run that, but when I click the submit button, its redirecting to itself page and showing 404.

Comment: Here is what you should do. Change the name of textarea from embed to myembed or something that is different. I tried this code in localhost and it keeps redirecting me to something with embed which means 'embed' name is already used somewhere else.